# Generating vector plot with curved arrows

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

Example below renders "A", it's rotated version, and displacement field. However, the arrows are straight instead of curved. What is the easiest way to get the curved version?

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(* setup equations *)
generateLetterA := 
  Module[{X, resolution, bitmap, binImg, vals, minX, maxX, minY, maxY,
     shifted, scaled},
   resolution = 8;
   bitmap = 
    Rasterize[Graphics[Text[Style["A", FontFamily -> "Times", 500]]], 
     "Image", ImageResolution -> resolution];
   binImg = Binarize[bitmap];
   X = N@PixelValuePositions[binImg, 0];
   
   {minX, maxX} = MinMax[X[[All, 1]]];
   {minY, maxY} = MinMax[X[[All, 2]]];
   shifted = (# - {minX, minY} & /@ X);
   factor = 1;
   scaled = #/{maxX - minX, maxY - minY}/
        factor - ({1/2, 1/2}/factor) & /@ shifted
   ];

x = generateLetterA;
ListPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> #[[2]], Axes -> None] & /@ {{x, 
   "Original"}, {x . RotationMatrix[Pi/2], "rotated"}}
arrowPlot[source_, target_] := 
  Show[Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Arrowheads[0.02], 
     MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {source, target}]}]];
arrowPlot[x, x . RotationMatrix[Pi/2]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this result?

```
Graphics[{{Red, Point@x, Blue, Point@RotationTransform[-π/2]@x}, 
  Black, Dashed, Arrowheads[{{.025, .5}}], Gray, 
  Arrow[Transpose@
    Table[RotationTransform[θ]@x, {θ, 
      Subdivide[0, -π/2, 20]}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
arrowPlot2[source_, target_] := 
  Show[Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Arrowheads[.02], 
     MapThread[GraphComputation`GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", 
          "Curvature" -> Sqrt @ Norm[#]}][{#, #2}, DirectedEdge[#, #2]] &,
      {source, target}]}]]

Show[arrowPlot2[x, x . RotationMatrix[Pi/2]], 
 ListPlot[#, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> #2] & @@@ 
 {{x, Blue}, {x . RotationMatrix[Pi/2], Red}}]
```

[image]